# Modifying a DataSet TableAdapter

Tags: c#, dataset, tableadapter

I am adding a field to a FormView where the data is generated by a ObjectDataSource.

I updated the ItemTemplate

```
<asp:Label ID="lblIsActive" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IsActive") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Using the tableadapter wizard, I updated the Dataset GetData tableadapter to include the new field. SELECT participantsid, first_name, middle_name, last_name, IsActive FROM participants

The auto-generated Dataset.Designer.cs file contains the IsActive property, but the Dataset.cs file doesn't.

When I view the page, I get a error:
DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'IsActive'.

Any ideas on how  to regenerate the Dataset.cs file? Thanks.

Comment: Delete all columns from the table apart from one (an arbitrary). Then use the qery wizard  again to recreate the columns. This should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the column to your dataset using the designer, then rebuild your project.

Comment: The field is displayed in the list of properties in the dataset. And when I run a test query in the TableAdapter, the IsActive field show up in the results. It just doesn't display when I try to bind it to the formview itemtemplate.

Comment: Make sure to clean your solution before building it. Sometimes you will have to delete the whole file and recreate it.